# Solve by the method of mutipliers $(y-z)p + (x-y)q = z-x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have given it a go and found one part of the answer, which is obtained by simply using multipliers $1,1,1$ and hence $u = x+y+z$.

In the second part, I use multipliers $x,z,y$ in order, and hence the denominator reduces to $0$, therefore the numerator is equal to $0$, thus

$x \Bbb dx + z \Bbb dy + y \Bbb dz = 0 \\
x \Bbb dx +  \Bbb d(zy+yz)=0 \\
x \Bbb dx + \Bbb d(2yz)=0 \\
x \Bbb dx + 2 \Bbb d(yz)=0 .$

On integration we get $\frac {x^2} 2 +2yz=v$, but in my book the answer is $\frac {x^2} 2 +yz=v$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $z \Bbb d y + y \Bbb d z =  \Bbb d(yz)$, not $\Bbb d(zy + yz)$. This solves your problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how zdy + ydz = d(yz) , is it substitution or what?

Comment: @user47024 It's like the derivative of two function

Comment: @user47024: How do you derive a product of two functions? You use $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$. Well, the same applies to differentials, i.e. just replace $'$ by $\Bbb d$ and the Leibniz rule stays the same.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks, now i get it